# How to show the chart made by C3PyO through django to html?

Tags: python, django

> when I ran this function the chart will show on ie browser not result.html.
>   There isn't anything info about C3PyO in internet so I came here to ask.
>   How to show the chart on result.html? 
>   C3PyO document ->https://benalexkeen.github.io/C3PyO/docs/

## views.py

```
import C3PyO as c3
    def chart(nominal_data):
         chart = c3.PieChart()
                chart.plot((nominal_data['男']/nominal_data['男']+nominal_data['女']), label='man')
                chart.plot((nominal_data['女']/nominal_data['男']+nominal_data['女']), label='woman')

                chart.show()
   return render(request, 'result.html',{'nominal_data': nominal_data,"chart":chart})
```

## result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

</script>
    <head>
        <title>I come from template!!</title>
        <style>
            body {
               background-color: pink;
            }
            em {
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        {{chart}}
        <h1><em>{{nominal_data}}</em></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your result.html , replace `{{ chart }}` to `{{ chart.as_html }}`. 
Otherwise use Graphos http://agiliq.com/demo/graphos/gchart/ That may be useful.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion.Unfortunately, it doesn't work when I replace {{chart}} to {{chart.as_html}}.I changed to use Graphos and it ran successfully.Thanks again!